# VueJS - replace text in DOM

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I am using elementUI's pagination component in my VueJS app.

I wish to replace the default 'Go to' text to 'Page' without altering the inner div:

```
<span class="el-pagination__jump">
   Go to
   <div class="el-input el-pagination__editor is-in-pagination">
      <!----><input type="number" autocomplete="off" min="1" max="6" class="el-input__inner"><!----><!----><!---->
   </div>
</span>
```

How can I do this? Do I have access to the DOM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with the localization settings. Since the default locale is Chinese, I assume you are already doing this in your `main.js`

```
import localeUI from 'element-ui/lib/locale'
import defaultLang from 'element-ui/lib/locale/lang/en' 
localeUI.use(defaultLang);
```

So you have to clone the English locale, modify the `el.pagination.goto` value and then use this new locale.

Comment: How do I use the new locale file? I am just replacing the PATH for defaultLang?

Comment: Yes, you point it to the modified locale file. Perhaps you can also try to still import the original, then modify it in-memory before the `localeUI.use()` call